# correlation between two variables(categorical and continuous) in python

Tags: python, anova

I am struggling on a simple problem where i need to check whether customer location has effect on number of defects.

Dataset is like. Location has 50 values and categorical in nature and defects is continuous.

```
location  defects
a            20
b            30
c            40
d            50
e            60
f            70
g            80
```

Comment: does my answer help?

Comment: do you mean ordinal or categorical, are you expecting the effect to increase from a to g?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy. You can use `LabelEncoder` to convert the categorical to numerical.

Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

#data
location = np.array(['a','b','a'])
defects = np.array([1,2,1])

# the encoder
lb_make = LabelEncoder()
converted= lb_make.fit_transform(location) # convert to numerical

print(converted)
array([0, 1, 0])

np.corrcoef(defects,converted)[0][1]
0.9999999999999998
```

Comment: thanks for the comment.but my question is how can i quantify relationship between categorical and numerical variable. how can i say how they are correlated. i know its easy when we both have continous variables

Comment: that's exactly what my answer provides. I correlate `location` with `defects`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think labelencoder has the demerit of converting to ordinal variables which will not give desired result. for example : if there 5 categories , levels will be coded as 1,2,3,4,5. and the correlation will be between these and location. if i change the orders, corr will be different.

Answer (score -2):

So you basically wanna calculate (ratio_for_location) = (number_of_defects_for_location) / (total_number_of_whatever_for_location) and check for outliers / find the function defect_ratio(location)?

Comment: no.its only whether location has effect on defect or not.

Comment: histogram helps. but problem is i have other categorical variables too in the dataframe.fine. I will post complete dataframe then.thank you